# I am trying to texture paint but the object keeps showing purple although it has a material of its own

Tags: uv, texture-painting

[here is the blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/62016e14e0284467a43d6a4ccc4b9e47)I want to add a blush to the cheeks of this emoji, so I decided to try texture paint. I used the SMART UV project but it keeps showing purple and it doesn't paint. If on the other hand, there is another way to add the[[image: The emoji][1]] blush to the emoji, it'd be great to know. Thank you.

Comment: your image shows a "multiplication" symbol, so maybe saving your image file would help?

Comment: Hello please share your file (just the important part) so that we understand what's missing: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/62016e14e0284467a43d6a4ccc4b9e47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are editing a stored image that you didn't include (pack) with your file:

[image]

And this is part of the problem that we'll return to (#2 below).

Problems:

1. you had no vertices assigned to the material "Blush". In EDIT mode, I went to your objects Material properties tab, clicked on Material (yellow), click Select, then clicked on Blush and clicked on Assign.  You can only have one matl at a time assigned to a vertex, you'd want to first fill the Blush canvass with your background/base color or load the image assigned to the face, and then "blush over it".

[image]

2. I selected Generated image (which I packed into the file for my example), and was able to paint.

[image]

Now you can paint inside blender in Texture mode or in the Image Editor (in Paint mode):

[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much